# Batch - using delayed expansion in writing to file

Tags: batch-file, dos

This is a part of my xml file:

```
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">dd32261_RealTimeRisk</anyType> 
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</anyType> 
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">dd32261</anyType>
```

Here is my code below:

```
for /R c:\ABC\TraderFolders\%tradersoeid%\PROD %%G in (Connections.xml) do (

MOVE "%%G" "%%G.temp"
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%b in ("%%G.temp") do (
set write=%%b

echo !write:%tradersoeid%=%usersoeid%! >> "%%G"
)
del "%%G.temp"
)
```

What the above code does is replaces any existance of tradersoeid which is "dd32261" with usersoeid which is "ak15000". This works perfect.

But what i want to do is to replace the first row occurance of "dd32261" as "dd32261_ak15000" and replace the second one as it is.

I tried something like this:

```
set "val1=>"
set "val2=_"    
set "str=%val1%%tradersoeid%%val2%"
```

so whenever it finds **>dd32261_** replace it with >dd32261_userid

and when it finds **>dd32261<** replace it with >usersoeid<

Thanks

```
echo off
set tradersoeid=dd32261
set usersoeid=ak15000
set ws_namestr=%tradersoeid%_%usersoeid%
set id_=%tradersoeid%_

for /R c:\ABC\TraderFolders\%tradersoeid%\PROD %%G in (Connections.xml) do (
MOVE "%%G" "%%G.temp"
pause>nul      
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("%%G.temp") do (
  set write=%%b
  for /f %%t in ("!id_!") do echo %%t
  for /F %%u in ("!ws_namestr!") do set newWrite=!write:%%t=%%u!

  echo !newWrite! >> "%%G"
  if not "!newWrite!" == "!write!" (
      set id_=%tradersoeid% 
      ws_namestr=%usersoeid%
   )
 )
   del "%%G.temp"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set tradersoeid=dd32261

for /R c:\ABC\TraderFolders\%tradersoeid%\PROD %%G in (Connections.xml) do (
   MOVE "%%G" "%%G.temp"
   set usersoeid=%tradersoeid%_ak15000
   for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%b in ("%%G.temp") do (
      set write=%%b
      for /F %%u in ("!usersoeid!") do set newWrite=!write:%tradersoeid%=%%u!
      echo !newWrite! >> "%%G"
      if not "!newWrite!" == "!write!" set usersoeid=ak15000
   )
   del "%%G.temp"
)
```

I assumed you want to replace "the first row occurance of "d32261" *in each file*.

P.S. I suggest you to change this line:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%b in ("%%G.temp") do (
```

by this one:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("%%G.temp") do (
```

"delims=" is the standard way to get *the entire line*. "tokens=*" change multiple spaces and tabs by just one space.

**EDIT**: *New version added*

```
set tradersoeid=dd32261
set usersoeid=ak15000

for /R c:\ABC\TraderFolders\%tradersoeid%\PROD %%G in (Connections.xml) do (
   MOVE "%%G" "%%G.temp"
   for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%b in ("%%G.temp") do (
      set write=%%b
      set newWrite=!write:%tradersoeid%_=%tradersoeid%_%usersoeid%_!
      if "!newWrite!" == "!write!" set newWrite=!write:%tradersoeid%=%usersoeid%!
      echo !newWrite! >> "%%G"
   )
   del "%%G.temp"
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and let you know.

Comment: But, I saw that the Connections.xml files sometimes do not have the first row. So in that case, it replaces the next occurance of tradersoeid with tardersoeid_usersoeid. I do not want that so I tried code like below:

Comment: `echo off
set tradersoeid=dd32261
set usersoeid=ak15000
set ws_namestr=%tradersoeid%_%usersoeid%
set id_=%tradersoeid%_
for /R c:\ABC\TraderFolders\%tradersoeid%\PROD %%G in (Connections.xml) do (
   MOVE "%%G" "%%G.temp"
   for /F "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("%%G.temp") do (
      set write=%%b
      for /f %%t in ("!id_!") do echo %%t
      for /F %%u in ("!ws_namestr!") do set newWrite=!write:%%t=%%u!
      echo !newWrite! >> "%%G"
      if not "!newWrite!" == "!write!" (
          set id_=%tradersoeid% 
          ws_namestr=%usersoeid%
      )
   )
   del "%%G.temp"
)`

Comment: So this way only if there is an underscore after the tradersoeid, it will replace with tradersoeid_usersoeid else just usersoeid. But this does not work.

Comment: Hi @Aacini, Adding the above bit of code in my question... It does not look good here

Comment: Excuse me, this is confusing... If the first file _line_ does not have dd32261, then the next occurance is the _first one_ and is replaced as you requested, right? Please, explain me when you want to use trader..._users... and when only users... in terms of _file lines_ (don't use "rows"). How is possible that a file do not have the first row? The first row in the file is the first row in the file, right?

Comment: @NewQueries: Check the new version I just added. Is it what you want?

Comment: `@Aacini`  Sorry for not being clear. This is confusing. The above xml file is just a "part" of my whole xml file. Hence, the row above, is not the first row in my actual XML file. As you can see, the first occurance of dd32261 is appended by "_RealTimeRisk" which is my project name. If there is such an occurance of dd32261, I want to replace it by tradersoeid_usersoeid. But, if there is just a plain occurance of dd32261 without the name of project after it, I want to replace it with just the usersoeid. Hope this was not confusing. Thanks for the new version :)

Comment: @NewQueries: OK, just confirm that the new version do precisely that! (I developed it to do that...)